# Sync PPA repos with ubuntu one

Tags: sync, ppa

It is possible to sync all the repos, the PPA too, and all the applications between computers with the same ubuntu one account?
I think that could be a great idea to improove the usage and the costumization of Ubuntu and computer nets.

Answer (score 3):

[**oneconf**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneconf)[image: Install oneconf] is designed for that.

Read more about oneconf here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneConf